# Firebase Rest Api:How To Use OrderBy() and StartAt() using The Last Key id

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using **firebase database rest API** in my android application using c# And my application gets 10 data from the firebase database when the page is opened and these data are ordered by (Views Count) using `.OrderBy("Views").LimitToLast(10)`So far I am getting the data correctly and it works correctly, as well as I store the last id in a public string because I get another 10 elements from firebase database when user scroll down the listview, But when I get the other 10 data and use `.StartAt(LastId).LimitToLast(10)` the firebase will return null (0) data,**Because** the keys that return are not sorted correctly when I use `.OrderBy("Views")` So I can't get the correct last id to get the data starting at the last id, I found a way to order the keys using `OrderByKey()` And fetching the correct last id and fetching other 10 data starting at last id, **but I want to fetch the data ordered by (Views) **,

**Summary: How can I get 10 elements from the firebase database ordered by ("Views") and at the same time I can get the other 10 elements starting at the last id for the first 10**

My JSON Structure :

```
{
  "Main" : {
    "News" : {
      "Categories" : {
        "Education" : {
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtp11En" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO0112ifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 12
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01dxifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 545
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01sdifhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 5
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifddhtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 200
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifdshtpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 1
          },
          "-Mn7-ZxkUPO01ifhtdxpEn" : {
            "Text" : "some text",
            "Title" : "some title",
            "Views" : 223
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance
And I thank Frank van Puffelen because he helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments on your previous question: the Firebase Realtime Database REST API will return the correct, filtered nodes, but they will not be in any defined order - as the order of the keys in a JSON object is undefined by definition. There is nothing you can do to change that.

What you'll need to do is re-order the results in your application code, and then determine the first/last one. If you do that for the [first/last of nodes](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10) you shared, you'll see that the first node has `Views` `33` and key `-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn`.

To get the previous page, you'd use:

https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/70102492/Main/News/Categories/Education.json?print=pretty&orderBy=%22Views%22&limitToLast=10&endAt=33,%22-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn%22

So:

- We `endAt=33,"-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn"`, which means we end at the first item of the next page. We include both the value of `Views` and the key in this parameter, since there may be multiple nodes with `Views` equal to `33` and in that case the database will use the key to select the correct node to end at.
- You might want to request 11 items instead of 10, given that you'e already shown the `-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification
I sorted the keys and got the last id correctly **-Mn7-ZxkUPO01iddfh2tpEn**, but the problem is `EndAt` does not support two arguments for (LastValue,LastId) It only supports one (string or double or long),And I tried to put the LastValue (33) in .EndAt() and it works,But as you said what if there are elements that match the same value (33), so what is the solution to pass the last value and last id

Comment: As shown in my answer: the REST API supports the two values. You'll have to look at the library you use, and see how it calls the REST API - and see if either you can already pass both values somehow, or if you need to request/make a change to the library.

Comment: It is really true and also as explained in the link that you posted, I  post a new issue in the library I use, or I will send the request manually, anyway. Your answers were beautiful and helped me a lot. I wish you good days, thank you 